# PHP Math: Why is mod (%) not working with fac(13)?

Tags: php, math, floating-point

Okay, this one is beyond me: I must be having a long day. Why does (13! mod 10) come out as 4, when the number ends in two 0s??

Try this out:

```
<?php $thirteen_fac = 6227020800;
echo $thirteen_fac % 10; ?>
```

Result is 4. Expected 0.

I must be forgetting something exceedingly obvious...

Comment: Works fine on 64 bit PHP.  Are you overflowing a 32 bit int in 32 bit PHP?  Echo your var before applying modulus to see if there's any overflow.

Comment: Sorry, this was basically pseudocode. Yep, I expected zero too. Don't know why I put ten. More evidence of a long day, I just started two variables with numbers. LOL

Comment: I'm on 64-bit. No overflow :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`6227020800` is too large for an integer (on a 32 bit system anyway). PHP will store it as float in your variable. The modulo operation will thus use an inexact up/downrounded number as basis.

Comment: You might be able to use the [`bcmath`](http://php.net/bcmath) or [`gmp`](http://php.net/gmp) functions probably.